# A strange behaviour shared variable issue in VB.net

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

When I was using VB.net , I came across a very strange behaviour, I created a simple test WPF project to reproduce it.  here is the details.  I have a very simple class, which when an instance is created, the class will create a test.txt file

```
Public Class Test
    Public Sub New()
        Using writer As New System.IO.StreamWriter("test.txt")
            writer.Write("test")
        End Using
    End Sub
End Class
```

Then in the Application.xaml.vb

```
Class Application

    ' Application-level events, such as Startup, Exit, and DispatcherUnhandledException
    ' can be handled in this file.
    Shared tt As New Test()
End Class
```

I simply define a shared variable. my expectation of this are, when I start the application, the variable will be initiated, and a "test.txt" file will be created.

If the Configuration is "Debug" , everything is fine. 
If the Configuration is "release", When I start press F5 in Visual Studio 2010, everything is fine as well, it worked as expected,  file had been create

But When I start it without debug, press (Ctrl+F5), the variable had not been initiated, file had not been created as I expected.

I am not fully understand why this happen, Can anyone help me out?

Thanks and regards

Comment: @Greg - Fair enough, I've removed it.

Answer (score 2):

Is this shared variable accessed somewhere? It could been removed due to compiler optimization. Try to add some code that uses the variable.

Comment: I also think that's a possible cause. You could just remove the code from the constructor into its own method, then call that method in your Main.

Comment: I didn't access the variable anywhere else, but I don't believe the compiler optimization removed it  as well, cause using ildasm , I can see it there.

Comment: It's not the vb compiler that optimizes, but the JIT compiler. That's why you see it in the IL.